# Item Drops In A Random Location On The Map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press `Tab` on my keyboard it should drop the item that I am holding, but instead it drops the items and spawns them in a random location on the map and rotates it self.

I have tried to use `tranform.position` and `transform.rotate` but it does nothing. The pick up function is in a deferent script.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public int selectedWeapon = 0;
    public Transform enviroment;

    void Start()
    {
        SelectWeapon();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int previousWeapon = selectedWeapon;

        // Use your own input controls to switch weapons (e.g., scroll wheel, number keys)
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
                selectedWeapon = 0;
            else
                selectedWeapon++;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon <= 0)
                selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
            else
                selectedWeapon--;
        }

        // Use number keys to directly select a weapon
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1 + i))
            {
                selectedWeapon = i;
            }
        }

        // Check if the selected weapon has changed
        if (previousWeapon != selectedWeapon)
        {
            SelectWeapon();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            Drop();
        }
    }

    void SelectWeapon()
    {
        int weaponIndex = 0;

        // Activate the selected weapon and deactivate the others
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
            if (weaponIndex == selectedWeapon)
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }

            weaponIndex++;
        }
    }

    void Drop()
    {

        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
                Destroy(weapon.gameObject);
                Debug.Log("lol");
                Instantiate(weapon.gameObject, enviroment);
                weapon.position = transform.position;
                weapon.Rotate(90.0f, 180.0f, 0.0f);

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: is this script on your player?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Instantiate methot like this:

```
Instantiate(Object, position, rotation, parent);
```